# ASP.NET AutoCompleteExtender CompletionListCssClass

Tags: asp.net, css, autocompleteextender

I have used AutoCompleteExtender in a asp.net applications and i wanted set max-height to CompletionListCssClass since i got many records around 75-150. My problem is even i have three recods on a AutoCompleteExtender it take 150px. I want to change the height dynamically. Is there any specific css property to do this. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
    .autocomplete_completionListElement 
    {  
    margin : 0px!important;
    background-color : White;
    color : windowtext;
    border : buttonshadow;
    border-width : 1px;
    border-style : solid;
    cursor : 'default';
    overflow : auto;
    font-family:Calibri;
    font-size:12px;
    text-align : left; 
    list-style-type : none;
    margin-left:0px;
    padding-left:0px;
    max-height:150px;
    width:auto;
    }
```

Comment: Your css looks ok.. nothing wrong with it. May be you should take a look at inner elements which are populating the lists.

Answer (score 0):

Add `min-height:50px` or set the min-height as per your requirement to CSS.

Comment: Not Worked!.Anyway thanks for your suggestion. When i apply it in to style it will remain in 50px area even i have more elements.